# How to change one column or another depending on value?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am working on a Tinder clone for school using node.js and mysql and have a system that involves liking and disliking people. I unfortunately based a lot of my database on a user's chosen username and am now coming up against the problem of when a user wants to change their username I need to change all instances of it in my database. (I know I should've used user ID's instead but at this point it's too late to change as the project is almost finished and it's only for learning purposes for school.) I'm having a problem changing the data in one column or another based on where the username exists. Example of my database table called likes:

```
Liker    | Liked
-------------------
jennifer | matt
jennifer | colin
jennifer | justin
joe1     | sarah
joe1     | tammy
joe1     | lindsay
celine6  | joe1
celine6  | curtis
```

So for example if joe1 has decided he now wants to go under the username buffdude27 I tried to use the following query in node using the mysql middleware to change all instances of his name in the table:

```
var change = ['buffdude27', 'buffdude27', 'joe1', 'joe1'];
connection.query('UPDATE likes SET liker = ? OR liked = ? WHERE liker = ? OR liked = ?', change, function(err, results){

...the actions I take after the query happens...
    });
```

The problem I'm having is that it will find all instances of joe1 and replace his username with a 0. What am I doing wrong and what is the proper way to do this? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The easiest way is to run two queries (one per column).

Comment: Why make life difficult - use two queries one for the liker column & one for the liked.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is the easiest way. Was just hoping there might be some way to do it in one query. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: There is a way using CASE or IF. But it is not worth it

Answer (score 0):

Either run two simple queries:

```
UPDATE likes SET liker = 'buffdude27' WHERE linker = 'joe1';
UPDATE likes SET liked = 'buffdude27' WHERE linked = 'joe1';
```

Or a more comlex one:

```
UPDATE likes 
SET liker = CASE WHEN linker = 'joe1' THEN 'buffdude27' ELSE linker END,
    liked = CASE WHEN linked = 'joe1' THEN 'buffdude27' ELSE linked END
WHERE 'joe1' IN (liker, liked)
```

An even better way would be to have a `users` table with columns `user_id` and `name`. And store references (foreign keys) in the `likes` table (`liker_user_id`, `liked_user_id`).

If a user decides to change his name, you only need to update the `name` column in the `users` table. All other tables referencing the `user_id` don't need to be changed.